Qute template: how to iterate over a map?
I need to iterate over a Map<String, String>
I've tried that template syntax:
{#for key in myTemplate.myMap.keyset}

but it raises:
{myTemplate.myMap.keyset}: Unsupported iterable type found: java.lang.Object

at the build time. However, I don't quite understand as a keyset is a set and, as such, it's iterable.

So this error might be produced when Qute does not have enough type information during type-safe validation. But we will need more information to find the exact cause. Ideally, a small code snippet/quarkus app that would demonstrate the problem.
By the way, you don't need to use the keyset in Qute. The loop section can iterate over map entries. I.e. {#for entry in myMap} works out-of-the box. And the entry represents a Map.Entry.

@Martin Kouba: Yeah, you're right, simply replacing myMap.keyset by myMap in the mentioned expression fixes the issues. Which is surprising as the documentation states that:

keys or keySet: Returns a Set view of the keys contained in a map {#for key in map.keySet}

Anyway, thanks for the suggestion. +1.

As I said - we would need more info to find out why the keySet does not work. It should.
